# How to print a matrix with a pointer that starts with 1?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to print something like `a[1][1]=11`, `a[1][2]=12` etc, so I coded this to avoid the pointer from starting at 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "nrutilz.h"
#define n 5
int main() {
    int a[n][n], i, j, x;
     for (i=1; i<n+1; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<n+1; j++) {
            a[i][j]=10*i+j;
        }
    }
    for (i=1; i<n+1; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<n+1; j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = %3d\n ",i,j,a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me my desired results, but it also gives me an Abort trap 6 error that stops me from using this matrix in the next step.

I know that I must be writing into a memory I don't own, but I don't know what Im supposed to change.

Comment: `int a[n+2][n]+2;` of course. Then you own the memory.

Comment: "to avoid the pointer from starting at 0". Why? If you think 0-based counting is too hard, your life as a C programmer will be very miserable and very short.

Comment: `int a[n+2][n+2] `worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @n.m. I'm not trying to become a programmer, It was a homework assignment and we were given no lectures on c so this was a "walking in the dark" situation

Comment: @loopers Then look at the answers and come into the light.

Comment: `a[n+1][n+1]` would suffice already. Be aware that all elements `a[0][x]` and `a[x][0]` remain uninitialised, though (so reading them results in undefined behaviour). You might prefer to initialise them anyway, and if only to 0. With integers (not floating point values!), `i < n+1` is equivalent to `i <= n`, I personally consider the latter nicer to read, but decide yourself...

Comment: Understandable, but it might prove too short to outlast even a couple of your homeworks. So please count from zero. It's not hard. If you have N things, their numbers are 0, 1, ..., N-1 and your `for` loops look lile `for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) ....`. See? Nothing mysterious.

Answer (score 3):

You are smashing your stack!
You have to remap your first 1 index back to the original 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

enum { n = 5 };

int main(void)
{
    int a[n][n];

    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; ++i) {
        for (int k = 1; k < n + 1; ++k) {
            a[i - 1][k - 1] = 10 * i + k;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; ++i) {
        for (int k = 1; k < n + 1; ++k) {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = %3d\n ", i, k, a[i - 1][k - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You got a problem in the array indexing.

```
for (i=1; i<n+1; i++)
```

should be

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
```

and likewise. Remember, C uses 0-based array indexing.

For the ***print*** part, you can simply add `1` to make the print appear like *1-based* (FWIW), something like

```
printf("a[%d][%d] = %3d\n ",i+1,j+1,a[i][j]); //add 1 to i and j value for printing
```

Comment: @KeineLust Just got to that.

Comment: I had no idea of making it look 1 based. Thanks!